# Create own or extend SimpleExpression in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, expression

I am using extensively simple expressions, however I found a problem, I would like to create a property transformation inside the like simple expression:

```
Restrictions.like(propertyName, value, getMatchMode());
```

transforms to

```
WHERE propertyName LIKE %value%;
```

I need to get this

```
 WHERE RAWTOHEX(propertyName) LIKE %value%;
```

using simple expressions, not sure if it is possible to extend simple expressions or make hibernate know I need the required transformation.

Kindly assist.

Comment: If you are not sure, just try it.

Comment: I tried, did not work :S